# Comparison failure on comparing two values

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to compare two variables one is getting fetched from database and other is a textbox value.

If comparison is successful then the if statement block will return the value as matched and if they don't else statement block will return `not matched`.

But it is always returning `not matched` even if I enter same value that is in the database.

My code is this:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(0);
   $user_id = 5;

   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   mysql_select_db('qurefle');
   if(! $conn )
   {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   if(isset($_POST["blccrcc"])){
     $sql = 'SELECT l_coupon_c FROM cc_generator WHERE unique_id = "'.$user_id.'"';

     $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval )
   {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
   {
      //fetching data
      $l_coupon_c = $row['l_coupon_c'];
      //Data Comparison
      $friend_cc = $_POST["lccrcc"];

      if ($l_coupon_c == $friend_cc) {
        echo"it is matched";
      }
      else{
    echo"Not Matched";
      }
  }//while bracket
}//if isset bracket  
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>LCC AND RCC Coupon Code Chain Extender</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<form method="POST" action="">
Friend cc: <input type="text" name="lccrcc"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Use Coupon Code" name="blccrcc">

</form>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: My Database snapshot is this]

Comment: They have the same encoding? for example both in utf-8?

Comment: did you trimed both the values by using trim() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trim` as well, sometimes there are some additional space issues too.

```
if(trim($l_coupon_c) == trim($friend_cc))
```

and `print_r($_POST);` to see the values of `POST`

Comment: Thanks a lot it is fixed ya i didn't added trim function.

Answer (score 0):

please pass character in capital letter(UPPERCASE) as per your database screenshot your data stored in upepercase 
or convert form data into uppercase using function strtoupper()

refer this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

i.e : strtoupper($_POST['lccrcc']);

it works in your case if you pass data in lowercase. or do same in reverse order with convert your stored data into lowercase with help of strtolower()

refer this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Comment: Thanks a lot i will take care of it too :)